# How to Ingest Data into AWS S3

Tags: api, amazon-s3, etl, palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

I'm working on a project to automate our dashboard refreshes by pulling data from our enterprise data management platform (Foundry Palantir).

Our workflow is: third party tool's data -> AWS S3 -> Foundry Palantir -> PowerBI grabs data to build dashboards.

Our analysts are currently manually downloading csv exports from a third party tool's website daily  in order to refresh dashboards.

The problem that I'm trying to solve is to ingest our third party app's data into AWS S3 and then into our data platform.

Where do I start?

I'd imagine an ETL needs to be built. This third party tool has a REST API reference: https://developers.arcgis.com/survey123/api-reference/rest/encode-url-params/

Comment: What do you mean by “ingest into S3”? S3 is literally (!) a *simple storage service*, i.e. you can upload static files to it. Upload works through a REST API, though you can also use the AWS CLI or one of the SDKs.

Comment: You could also skip S3 and directly import into Foundry: 
https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/external-transforms/

Answer (score 0):

S3 is a storage layer, you don't need it to do Analysis on top of Foundry, since you could import the data directly to Foundry using [external transforms](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/external-transforms/#calls-to-external-systems).